# function over more than one list

Tags: r, list, sapply

I do not use that many functions but when I do I tend to use an anon function and some form of `apply` .  I now however am trying to write a function that works over items in a list.

There are two lists that each have many items (by item I mean e.g. `mylist1[1]`).  All items are dataframes. I want to take the first dataframe from `mylist1` and the first dataframe from `mylist2` and run a bunch of functions over the columns in those dataframes.  Then take the 2nd `mylist1` item and the 2nd `mylist2` item and so on...

Below is the sort of thing I am used to writing but clearly does not work in this case with two lists.  Can anyone help me out with a fast way to figure out how I should approach this using something other than `sapply` method that seems to be causing the main problem.

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(1:10)
z <- c(rep("x", 5), rep("y", 5))
df <- data.frame(cbind(a, b, z))
mylist1 <- split(df, z)
mylist2 <- split(df, z)

myfunction <- function(x, y) 
{

    a <- as.data.frame(x[1])
    b <- as.data.frame(y[1])
    meana <- mean(a[1])
    meanb <- mean(b[1])
    model <- lm(a[1]~b[1])
    return(c(model$coefficients[2], meana, meanb))
}

result <- sapply(mylist1, mylist2, myfunction)
```

I also just thought do people think it would be better to `subset` by `z` rather than `split` and do the function that way?

Comment: Hi. What's the value of `n` on (e.g.) line 4?

Comment: sorry `n` should be `z` .  corrected it.

Comment: What's the difference between `mylist` and `mylist2`? At the moment, you have both as `split(df, z)`.

Comment: in reality they are lists with the same number of elements but the size of the data frames within are different. different number of columns and rows.  I just doubled `mylist` here for (I thought) simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing exactly the use case for `mapply`.

```
result <- mapply(myfunction,x=mylist,y=mylist2)
```

Unfortunately your example doesn't seem to enjoy being passed two data.frames (x, y 's first elements are both data.frames, which `x[1]` and `y[1]` would seem to contradict).

Comment: thank you @gsk I had a closer look at mapply and it seems to be the right one.  I see the problem now with the `x[1]` etc. can you suggest an improvement?

Comment: @user1322296, I see a few other problems that you need to fix. Your `data.frame(cbind(...` code converts your numeric values to factors. Just use `data.frame` without `cbind`. Some lines in your function can also be reduced. For example you can directly use `meana <- mean(x[[1]][, 1])` (that is, the first column as a vector from the first item in the list) instead of first creating `a`. I *think* also that for your `model`, you might also need to use the same `[[1]][, 1]` structure. Can you post what you expect as the result of this example?

Comment: thank you gsk I played around more and I get something pretty much what I was asking for but changed all my notation.  I'll try and get to grips and see if i can improve it more.

Comment: @user1322296 To debug `*apply` functions, I find it simpler to create a test dataset that represents the data from a single iteration.  Write your function based on those, then run the apply command.  For instance, set `x <- mylist[[1]]` and `y <- mylist2[[1]]`, and write your `myfunction` based on those.  You'll quickly see where the errors are coming from.  The other way do to this is to make the first line of `myfunction` a call to `browser()` and then run the `mapply` command.