# Taking column mean over a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, aggregate, group-summaries

Here's what I'm trying to do. My data frame has a factor variable, "country", and I want to split the data frame based on country. Then, I want to take the column mean over every variable for every country's data frame.

Data here: https://github.com/pourque/country-data

I've done this so far...

```
myList <- split(df1, df1$country)
for(i in 1:length(myList)) {
aggregate <- mapply(myList[[i]][,-c(38:39)], colMeans)
}
```

(I'm not including the 38th and 39th columns because those are factors.)

I've read this ([function over more than one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051087/function-over-more-than-one-list)) , which makes me think mapply is the answer here...but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
'myList[[i]][, -c(38:39)]' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Maybe I'm formatting it incorrectly?

Comment: Why bother splitting in to separate data frames? Just use data.table or dplyr.

Comment: This is turning into a good post now !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data.table answer:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = country, .SDcols = -c('age', 'gender')]
```

Now tidier syntax with deselection in .SDcols, thanks to user Arun

To explain what's happening here:

- `setDT(df1)` make the data.frame a data.table
- `lapply(.SD, mean)` for each column in the subset of data, take the `mean`
- `by = county` do this by groups split according to `country`
- `.SDcols = -c('age', 'gender')` omit `age` and `gender` columns from the subset of data

Comment: I kind of don't like the readability of this vs some of the other answers. Any other data.table people want to suggest an improvement?

Comment: Instead of the `setdiff` thing, couldn't you just use `.SDcols`?

Comment: Could specify all the desired cols to .SDcols, but that seems about the same as the above. Is there a tidy way to use .SDcols to omit specified columns?

Comment: `setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = country, .SDcols = -c("age", "gender")]`

Comment: It looks like the latest version has nicer syntax for `.SDcols`, yeah, in items 14-17 here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table#changes-in-v195--in-development-on-github Even with the CRAN version of `data.table` you could do `df1[
  , lapply(.SD, mean), by=country,.SDcols=setdiff(names(df1),c('age','gender'))]`, though, right?

Comment: Aha, thanks @Arun! Didn't know you could do deselection with `-` in `.SDcols`. @Frank, yes def, but that seemed similar is all i meant (in that it still requires setdiff)

Answer (score 7):

It's straightforward in base R using `aggregate` without the need to `split` the data.frame into a list beforehand. Here's an example using the built-in iris data where you compute the `mean` of all variables except those in the first and second column by group of `Species`:

```
data(iris)
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris[-(1:2)], mean)
#     Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1     setosa        1.462       0.246
#2 versicolor        4.260       1.326
#3  virginica        5.552       2.026
```

The `.` inside `aggregate` is used to specify that you want to use all remaining columns of the data.frame except the grouping variable (Species in this case). And because you specify `iris[-(1:2)]` as input data, the first and second columns are not used either.

---

For your data, it should then be something like:

```
aggregate(. ~ country, df1[-c(38:39)], mean)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you for the thorough explanation! When I run it, though, it still averages gender (col. 39) instead of omitting it. (Not a big deal for the data, but is there a way to prevent this?)

Comment: @Anshu, can you try again please with the slightly modified code at the bottom?

Comment: Or try using `df1[-c("age", "gender")]` inside aggregate

Comment: It's especially weird that I'm getting averaged gender values of >3 since the only gender choices are supposed to be 1 or 2. E.g., df1[df1$country=="AF",] gives only one observation whose gender is 2, but the aggregate gives gender=3!

Comment: The modified version doesn't seem to be working, and attempting df1[-c("age", "gender")] gives the warning "invalid argument to unary operator" :(

Comment: Thats strange. I haven't downloaded your data yet. Might do that when I'm back on my computer

Comment: @Anshu, I downloaded your data, read it into R and then ran `x <- aggregate(. ~ country, df1[-c(38:39)], mean)`. It produces the correct output and doesn't include the columns "gender" or "age". There must have been a typo in the code you tried or perhaps a different data structure than in the example on github.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I got it to work in the end...thanks for all your help :D

Answer (score 6):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    select(-age, -gender) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Comment: You could also unselect the two columns inside the summarise_each

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on keeping all in list:

```
#split and make list of df
myList <- split(df, df$country)

#aggregate without age and gender
my_aggregate <- function(df_inlist) {
  df_inlist <- aggregate(.~country, df_inlist[ , -c(38, 39)], mean)
}

#Apply aggregate function on all data frames in the list
out <- lapply(myList, function (x) {
  my_aggregate(x)
})
```

`out` is a `list` of data.frames for each country and colmeans over variables. How put it all together in a data.frame :

```
composite_df <- do.call(rbind, out)
```